# Do I need to implement certificates when communicating using SSLServerSocket and SSLSocket?

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I have an application that communicates via Sockets. Right now, I need to change the ServerSocket and Socket used to receive and send data, respectively, for its respective implementations of SSL/TLS.

I used the code below to convert from ServerSocket and Socket to SSLServerSocket and SSLSocket and kept the rest of the code untouched.

```
//On client    
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(serverAddress, serverPort);

//On server
SSLSocket socket;
SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket ) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(serverPort);
socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
```

Since I'm still learning how to secure mobile applications communications, I have some doubts if this is enough to secure the commucation or do I need to specify custom certificates?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it secure the server must have a certificate.